# reference to iterator not compiling in visual studio 2017

Tags: c++, visual-c++

In my project in Visual c++ in visual studio 2015, I used references to iterators.

I updated to vs2017 today, but the compiler appears to have changed more than I thought. Hopefully I can resolve most problems, but some I don't know why it would change.

For example, I used the snippet

```
for (auto& it = stack.begin(); it != stack.end() /* not hoisted */; /* no increment */)
    {
        if (it->second->empty()) { stack.erase(it++); }    // or "it = m.erase(it)" since C++11
        else
        {
            auto obj = move(it->second);
            stack.erase(it);
            return move(obj);
        }
    }
```

where `stack` is a `std::map<float, std::unique_ptr<StackableObj>`.

It worked fine before, but in vs2017 does not compile, instead it produces the type error

```
Error   C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<_Ty>>>' to 'std::_Tree_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tree_simple_types<_Ty>>> &'.
```

What do I do about this, or where do I look in order to know what has been changed? Googling some terms didn't give any specific answers to what is going on.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why would you want a reference there at all?

Comment: You were taking advantage of non-conforming behavior, whereby MSVC by default allowed binding a temporary to a non-const reference. Apparently, it doesn't anymore. Just drop the ampersand - it doesn't make sense to use a reference there.

Comment: If it used to work fine, that was just an accident.

Comment: I suspect that `stack.erase(it++);` could be undefined, but I can't find chapter and verse. (I would file it under "too clever; rewrite" just for raising doubts.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non-const reference to an rvalue is not valid. See [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSLTBW_2.3.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r3.cbclx01/cplr116.htm) for more on the topic:

> By default, the compiler cannot bind a non-const or volatile lvalue reference to an rvalue.

The most optimal solution here is dropping `&`, since copying iterators is cheap.